# plot theme does not work fine using bslib package in R shiny

Tags: r

I am trying to change theme in a shiny app using 'bslib' package. I also use ggplotly and plot_ly function. The theme works fine for ggplotly function but does not work for plot_ly function.

[image]

```
library(shiny)
library(plotly)
library(bslib)
thematic::thematic_shiny(font = "auto")

ui <- fluidPage(
  theme = bs_theme(),
 fluidRow(
    column(6, plotlyOutput(outputId ="p_plotly",width = "100%", height ="100%")  )
    ,        column(6, plotlyOutput(outputId ="p_ggplotly",width = "100%", height ="100%")  )
     ))

server <- function(input, output) {
  bs_themer()
  output$p_plotly<-renderPlotly({
iris %>% plot_ly(x=~Sepal.Length,y=~Sepal.Width)
})
output$p_ggplotly<-renderPlotly({
 plt<-ggplot(iris,aes(x=Sepal.Length,y=Sepal.Width))+geom_point()
 ggplotly(plt)
})
}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

How to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

The bslib package does not support plotly graphs for the time being.

Comment: Its supporting now